# Anybody know what is this scroll library http://rdcm.com/?

Tags: jquery, scroll, parallax, perspective

I found a site of http://rdcm.com/ and there is cool app cube scrolling when you drag mousewheel. So  anybody know how do this jquery library call and where can I find the documentation about that? 
Google don't know about that.=(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could render the same effect with [this plugin](http://paulrhayes.com/experiments/cube-3d/touch.html).
There will probably be some settings to only allow x-axis rotation.

Here is the `keydown` event, you can now add your own `mousewheel` event based on this :

```
...
$(document).keydown(function(evt) {
            switch(evt.keyCode)
            {
                case 37: // left
                    viewport.move({y: viewport.y - 90});
                    break;

            case 38: // up
                evt.preventDefault();
                viewport.move({x: viewport.x + 90});
                break;

            case 39: // right
                viewport.move({y: viewport.y + 90});
                break;

            case 40: // down
                evt.preventDefault();
                viewport.move({x: viewport.x - 90});
                break;

            case 27: //esc
                viewport.reset();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        };
...
```

---

Update 1:

> Here is a [Live Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZYZpQB) I permiss myself to edit in order to give you another 3D cube effect exemple

This is based on an old SO answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20585166/2754447)

Comment: Thanks for answer. I try to find only cube scroll by mousewheel. I found [this plugin](http://www.jqueryscript.net/layout/jQuery-Based-One-Page-Scrolling-Navigation-with-3D-Transforms.html) and [this](http://www.jqueryscript.net/layout/Fullscreen-3D-One-Page-Scrolling-Effect-with-jQuery-CSS3.html) but they are not such that site.

Comment: See "Update 1" in my answer.